# symfony 3 collectionType: index of the current object is shown: how to change it from the form builder

Tags: label, subform

I am embedding a collection of forms using collectionType (Symfony 3). 
I need to change the name of the label of the subform. 
Thanks to the answer of an other question "Symfony2 form collection: Index of the current object is shown", I now know how to use "entry_option".

```
->add('parameterValues', 
CollectionType::class, array(
'entry_type' => ParameterValueType::class, 
'label' => "fixed_label", 
'entry_options' => ['label' => "label_I_want_to_change_depending_on_Parameter_Value"]
```

But as far as I know, you can only provide a string of letter, which means that all my subform will have the same label using this technic...

Is there any way to deal with it on back-end, (maybe delegating it to the embedded form ?)

Thank you all for your suggestion :)

Comment: You can do it via the template this way -> https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11819#issuecomment-54072462     let me check for a way to do it in the form

Comment: also,   WHAt exactly would you like to put there ..   depending on what you want the label to be, you could just pass it into your form via the form options, and then use it to build your label from there ..

Comment: So my "parameterValues" all have different names that are stored in a related table. I want to be able to do something like $parameterValues->getNameList()->getName(), and show this name as the label of the sub-form (=parameterValue). This is previously formated.